# Oracle apex 21.2.3 Datepicker

Tags: oracle-apex

We updated apex to version 21.2.

Now we are having issue with datepicker component. When we select any date up to the 28th of the month, the date is correct in the component. But for dates greater than 29, the dates are wrong.

For example, if I choose the date 29/03 becomes 01/03, if I choose 30/03 it becomes 02/03.

The date format choose is DD/MM/YYYY.

Any ideas?

[For example, when a choose 30/03 (march)][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiNY6.png

[it turns like 02/03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdcIq.png)

Comment: I tried it on apex.oracle.com which currently runs Apex **21.2.0** and - no such problems (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U58C.jpg). You said you have **21.2.3** ? Maybe it is a bug in that version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in the 21.2.2 PSE caused by changes to the underlying date parser & formatter because of other bugs in this area.

It has been fixed in patch 21.2.3.

c.f. https://twitter.com/JKaschuba/status/1487556202242400260

Comment: This may have been fixed, but they broke something else, the datepicker cuts off my time to 00:00:00 after exiting the component in version 21.2.3

Comment: Hi @Tomasz, the team here tried to reproduce that issue on 21.2.3 but haven't been able to yet. Can you provide more details? e.g. have you enabled the Show Time attribute? What date/time format has been set on the item?

Comment: export from 21.2.3 with this problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/2er3shr7sc3v46u/f108.sql?dl=0

Comment: Hi @Tomasz, thanks for providing a demo, we could reproduce the bug and this will be addressed. As a workaround for now, just use a different format mask like YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS or DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS

Comment: Hi @DanielHochleitner  I know, after 2 days of combining I came to this, but I didn't want to suggest here because it doesn't matter anyway;)

Comment: Why doesn't anyone test subsequent patches effectively? It can't be that one patch fixes one thing and breaks another. This may be the reason why APEX is not suitable for large systems (1000 pages+) !